# Greasemonkey unsafeWindow Vk

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, vk

I'm coding greacemonkey userscript for Vk comment automation.

And can't understand why I cant access to object.

Vk window obj have two different **Composer** and **composer** objects (the same words, but first capital lower). From *unsafeWindow* Composer is accessable, but lowercapital object composer return undefined.

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    .....
    some code
    finding post, openning comment form, pasting text
    need to call:
    unsafeWindow.composer.addMedia.checkMessageURLs("Comment text<br />http://example.com",true);
    .....
    console.log(unsafeWindow.Composer); // return object
    console.log(unsafeWindow.composer); // return undefined
}
```

if run

```
composer.addMedia.checkMessageURLs("Comment text<br />http://example.com",true);
```

directly in browser console - all ok.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`composer` (lowercase) is created on demand, long after the Greasemonkey script runs.

To access it from the script, you need to wait for it. Something like:

```
var composerChkTmr  = setInterval (doStuffWith_composer, 222);

function doStuffWith_composer () {
    if (typeof unsafeWindow.composer === "undefined")
        return;

    clearInterval (composerChkTmr);

    // DO WHATEVER, WITH unsafeWindow.composer HERE.
}
```